# Format BigDecimal without scientific notation with full precision

Tags: java, string-formatting, bigdecimal

I'd like to convert a `BigDecimal` to `String` for printing purposes but print out all digits without scientific notation. For example:

```
BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(12334535345456700.12345634534534578901);
String out = d.toString(); // Or perform any formatting that needs to be done
System.out.println(out);
```

I'd like to get `12334535345456700.12345634534534578901` printed. Right now I get: `1.23345353454567E+16`.

Comment: `System.out.println(out);` not `System.out.println(output);`

Comment: Part of the problem is `12334535345456700.12345634534534578901` is truncated to `1.23345353454567E+16` even before the value is passed into the `BigDecimal` constructor, because constant double values in your code don't have that much precision.  You can verify this by simply trying to store it in a `double` variable instead and printing it out: http://ideone.com/j5FKp1.  You need to start with the value as a string if you want the extra precision.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To preserve the precision for a `BigDecimal` you need to pass the value in as a `String`

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("12334535345456700.12345634534534578901");
System.out.println(d.toPlainString());
```

Comment: It will only print 12334535345456700

Comment: Prints `12334535345456700.12345634534534578901` for me :)

Comment: Prints out fine for me to. Are you using `BigInteger` by any chance?

Comment: for me it prints 12334535345456700 only . Dont know why?

Comment: @AchintyaJha: You are including the quotes around the number, right?  That was a change from the original code (albeit not clearly explained)

Comment: This would still print in scientific notation for some numbers like `2E+2` for string `"200"`. Use the `toPlainString()` on the `BigDecimal` instead. `new BigDecimal("4930592405923095023950238502395.3259023950235902").toPlainString()`

Answer (score 24):

The `BigDecimal` class has a `toPlainString` method. Call this method instead of the standard `toString` and it will print out the full number without scientific notation.

**Example**

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("4930592405923095023950238502395.3259023950235902");
System.out.println(b.toPlainString());

Output: 4930592405923095023950238502395.3259023950235902
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a `DecimalFormat`:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");  
String output = df .format(myBD);
System.out.println(value + " " + output);
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use this

```
BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(12334535345456700.12345634534534578901);
String out= d.toPlainString();
System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: -1 The problem is in the precision of the original number being passed as a double.  You could at least do your due diligence and test this with ideone, which takes all of 30 seconds: http://ideone.com/n137Cs

Comment: how come did you accept that new BigDecimal(String value); from Reimeus can work? i guess BigDecimal.valueOf does not accept Strings in constructor? does it?

Comment: Right, I believe `valueOf` is only for passing in numeric values.  You will need to use the constructor to pass in a string value.

Comment: BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf("12334535345456700.12345634534534578901"); //is a compile time error

The method valueOf(long) in the type BigDecimal is not applicable for the arguments (String)
.
.
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("12334535345456700.12345634534534578901"); //correct one..