# Work around Java BigDecimal outputting e-notation in .NET WCF SOAP client

Tags: java, wcf, .net-core, soap, wsdl

We have a .NET 8 project (though this was also an issue in .NET 7 and .NET Framework 4.8).

We have a vendor SOAP service - they give us a WSDL and we auto-generate a WCF client in Visual Studio.

This WSDL is *very* large, and results in many thousands of lines of C# autogenerated code.

We have a problem with one field that causes serialisation errors.

In the WSDL this is defined as:

```xml
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="spend" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
```

So in the C# generated code this is a `System.Decimal`/`decimal`.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=17)]
public System.Nullable<decimal> spend { ...
```

However, in the SOAP API response we get:

```xml
<ns:spend>0E-10</ns:spend>
```

This is floating point e-notation, valid for a IEEE754-1985 floating point number, but specifically [not valid for a `decimal`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#decimal) - .NET crashes when parsing it.

In case this was a bug in .NET's SOAP implementation we also tested it with https://www.soapui.org, with the same result.

I *think* this is the correct behaviour - `0E-10` can become a valid `decimal`, but `12345E-10` would lose data and you don't want that to happen silently.

We know this vendor uses Java, and this appears to be a bug in Java's `BigDecimal` type. It's been an issue with SOAP implementations like [JAXB for a long time](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/386). By default Java's `BigDecimal.toString()` outputs e-notation. Apparently this [isn't to hard to fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834879/format-bigdecimal-without-scientific-notation-with-full-precision) but let's assume this vendor isn't going to do that.

We *could* work around this by overriding the type in the generated code:

```cs
public System.Nullable<double> spend {
```

But then we potentially have inaccuracies (this field holds a cash value) and need to make this change again every time the vendor updates their WSDL (about once every 3 months) and this becomes a nasty bit of technical debt.

Is there a way in WCF or using Microsoft's SOAP tools to add a string-parser for this specific field? Or any `decimal` property from this provider?

Has anyone else worked around this? Java has had this bug for 20 years, there must be other .NET SOAP clients of Java services that had to handle it?

Comment: `XmlSerializer` doesn't support custom formats for primitives like `decimal`, `double`, `DateTime` and so on.  The standard workaround is to mark the real property with `[XmlIgnore]` and use a surrogate `string` valued property.  See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17438468) to [XML deserialization crashes on decimal parse due to formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17437946) as well as [Can you specify format for XmlSerialization of a datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1118833).  Be sure to parse and format the string using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: @dbc thanks but this is autogenerated code - line 8478 out of 31338. Adding `[XmlIgnore]` and a `string` surrogate gets around losing data for `double` to `decimal` conversion, but the real pain is manually editing a huge autogenerated file every time the WSDL changes.

Comment: Then you may need to consider creating a customized `XmlCodeExporter`.  See e.g. [XmlCodeExporter and nullable types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42295155/3744182).  Or maybe you could sanitize the XML before deserializing by using an XSLT transform or something similar.

Comment: @dbc we're on .NET 8, I'm not sure that we could even consider a library so old that it doesn't even support nullables (added in .NET Framework 2 around 20 years ago) even if this is SOAP. Inline XSLT would be a significant performance bottleneck as well as a lot of work to implement, but I'm not even sure how they could be applied without some kind of proxy between WCF and the SOAP service?

Comment: `XmlCodeExporter` supports nullable types, just not the way that querent wanted.  Anyway, WCF is very old technology.  `XmlSerializer` dates from .NET 2 and `DataContractSerializer` dates from .NET 3.  How are you using WCF in .NET 8?  Are you using CoreWCF?

Comment: Since the code is automatically generated from the WSDL document (it should be via svcutil.exe). I also think you can refer to the documentation for CoreWCF.